# MSTR - Dynamic Header Name for Grid in Dossier

Tags: microstrategy

In MSTR dossier, is there any way to include date in the grid's column header?

Example:

Total Value (Pre Year End) December 31 2022, Total Value (Pre Month End) June 31 2023, Total Value (Current Date) July 30, 2023

The date part will vary in the header based on the selected date.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the header and dynamic text in the dossier.
Check the document,
https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/Current/MSTRWeb/WebHelp/Lang_1033/Content/Adding_dataset_objects_to_a_text_field.htm
https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/Current/MSTRWeb/WebHelp/Lang_1033/Content/Adding_dossier_information_to_a_text_field.htm